# Can Jmeter simulation Multiple people stay online at the same time ？

Tags: testing, jmeter

as title
I have a project, need to simulate 1000 user stay online and continuously perform search actions.
Is there any way to achieve it ? or give me some keywords .
i just use JMeter 1 day , need some help to finish this project.

The current situation is ,
I can make it execute login > search.

i tried Constant Timer but it not working.

Comment: This is exactly what Jmeter does. You need to create Thread Group and add HTTP samplers for all the requests you want to simulate. If you need thinking time (delay) between requests you can use Constant timer. Unfortunately you need a lot things so not sure if this can be fixed in simple question.

Answer (score 0):

The key element where you define virtual users and their behaviour is [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

[image]

If you set up your Thread Group like this it will kick off 1000 users and will run them for the given duration. By default JMeter will execute the next request as soon as it receives response from the previous request, if you want to slow JMeter down a little bit you can use [Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer)

Login Request can be put under [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)

Example Test Plan outline:

[image]

Comment: yes! it works,So detailed step by step explanation  thanks so much!!!